# Android CardView/FloatingActionButton transparent color not show properly

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio, android-layout

I am new in android studio. 
I create a application in side I'm use 20% transparent color like `#C8FF8066` normal color is `#FF8066`

In card view and floating button show in side diamond shadow?

- normal color work properly but 20% transparent color not work

[image]

```
<com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/createBtnFloating"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:backgroundTint="@color/AppColor"
    android:src="@drawable/plus"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
    android:transitionName="CreateNewNote"
    app:borderWidth="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:tint="@color/colorWhite"
    tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />
```

Comment: That's Android's material shadow glitch that's been around since Lollipop. The easiest way to get rid of it is to use only opaque backgrounds; otherwise, you could disable the shadow. To disable it altogether on `Button`s, you'll need to set `android:stateListAnimator="@null"`, but on others like `CardView` you can simply set the `elevation` to zero, as mentioned in the answer below. If you really actually need translucent/transparent backgrounds and the shadow just without the glitch, it'll take some sort of workaround, AFAIK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to add this attribute:

```
app:elevation="0dp"
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).